# Silverlight: DataContractSerializer cannot handle read only collection properties

Tags: silverlight, serialization, collections, silverlight-4.0, datacontractserializer

For our Silverlight Project (SL4) I'm using a Model which might contain Lists (`IList<AnotherModel>`). According to good practice and rule [CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182327(VS.80).aspx)
 the `IList` properties don't have a public setter. We serialize the Model using the DataContractSerializer which is working. But when I try to deserialize, a SecurityException is thrown by DataContractSerializer's `ReadObject(Stream)` Method, complaining that the target property (pointing to the `IList` property) cannot be set due to a missing public setter.

Since the `DataContractSerializer` is sealed and neither extendable nor flexible so I currently see no chance to add some kind of additional rules which allow to deserialize the `ILists` using a foreach-loop on `Add()` method or some other method of transferring the collection items.

I've also tried to dig into `DataContractSerializer` source (using Reflector) to create a little fork but it looks like i'd have to dig very deep and replicating whole serialization classes doesn't seem to be a viable solution.

Do you see another chance to serialize a List with no public setter using the `DataContractSerializer`?

Thank you very much in advance for your ideas!

---

**UPDATE**
Solved using XmlSerializer.

---

Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In our case, we found out that we were not strictly bound to the `DataContractSerializer`, and interestingly, the `XmlSerializer` **DOES support** serialization of read-only ILists! In fact, it even **doesn't allow** a public setter for the IList interface in this case (cannot deserialize interface property) but (de-)serializing the ILists items works like a charm.

Only change for us was adding `[XmlInclude]` attributes in addition to `[KnownType]` (and of course, replacing the few lines from `DataContractSerializer.WriteObject(...)` to `XmlSerializer.Serialize(...)`.

Thanks for your support! =)

Answer (score 1):

Use concrete (mutable) types and give DCS what it wants.

It works well for me (I usually *only* specify concrete types in DataContractSerializable classes). The entire approach of generic serialization is a wash and comes with cavaets -- pick your battles. Alternatively, use another approach such as ISerializable (uhg).

Comment: Thank you! (I've chosen another solution)